# How do I play an animation using lib3ds?

Tags: animation, 3dsmax

I am having trouble playing an animation of a `.3ds` object using lib3ds.

I am able to load the .3ds model with lib3ds. But I can't find a way to play (for example) my 'walk' animation. Where can I find the animation data and how can I play the animation using lib3ds?

Comment: I don't know how lib3ds but in version 1.3 there is an example folder with the file named 3dsplay.c . It's not a tutorial, just code, but apparently it shows how to play an animation.

Comment: Just wondering, I edited the post. Why does it say @Sam Hocevar did it? His "edit" didn't change my changes to the original post. Just curious. How does it work?

Comment: @Sidar I approved your edit and further removed the signature at the bottom of the post, so it's that second edit that appears. You can still see yours in the history.

Comment: @SamHocevar ah yes, missed that.

Answer (score 1):

lib3ds only provides access to the data within `.3ds` files, along with some utility functions. It does not appear to have any kind of built-in playback functionality. You will need to build that yourself, but to do so you will need to access the data that lib3ds has loaded up.

lib3ds exposes `Lib3dsTrack` objects for various nodes in the file which define keyframe tracks for various attributes of the node.

You are probably interested in the tracks of `Lib3dsMeshInstanceNode`, which are:

```
Lib3dsTrack pos_track;
Lib3dsTrack rot_track;
Lib3dsTrack scl_track;
Lib3dsTrack hide_track;
```

These tracks define keyframes for position, rotation, scale, and visibility of the mesh. The keyframes are of type `Lib3dsKey` and contain value information as well as flags indicating which *type* of value information to use for that key (not all keys have sane values in all value fields).

There are various utility functions (in the `track_eval_*` family) that allow you to evaluate the value of some specified track at some specified time *t*, which can help you in processing the data in the tracks so you don't have to do it all yourself.